# Restrict access to DTO to message service and localhost with ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, publish-subscribe, servicestack-bsd

I want to restrict the access to a service method to the local message service in ServiceStack v3. I do not want to allow any request from external machines.

I am using the in memory `IMessageService` so all pub/sub is being done within the same machine.

I have registered the `ServiceController.ExecuteMessage` handler to the dto.

I have tested different configurations but the pub/sub is only working when I use the following attribute:

```cs
[Restrict(InternalOnly=true)]
```

or

```cs
[Restrict(AccessTo=EndpointAttributes.LocalSubnet | EndpointAttributes.MessageQueue)]
```

It does not work when using `LocalhostOnly=true` or `AccessTo=EndpointAttributes.Localhost` or `EndpointAttributes`.

I wonder if this is the expected behaviour. So it is not possible to limit, further, the access to a service that it is going to be executed by the `IMessageService` controller?

Comment: Maybe try creating a custom request filter?

Comment: A custom pre-request filter could be used to customize access, although I prefer to used builtin functionality whenever I can. I just can't find a reason why message services require Subnet permission.